# What is show('...') in php?

Tags: php

I hate to ask what may be a simple question, but I'm still new to php and learning as I go. I came across a php file with this snippet that appears to do the same thing as include(), but I can't find documentation on it.

```
<?php show('header'); ?>
```

Is it custom or am I not looking hard enough? If it is custom, how do I find where it may be defined at so I can understand it better. To my knowledge there's no frameworks being used.

Comment: Here's where a good IDE comes in. For predefined function, any good IDE will show you in a different color plus autocompletion (very handy with long php function names and inconsistancy in camel case and underscores).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a custom function. When in doubt .. always check http://php.net

If you want to find it in your code just run something like this (if a UNIX user):

```
grep "function show(" . -ir
```

Comment: oooo I was off by 2 seconds!

Comment: Thanks - I checked through the manual and didn't see it. Just wanted to make sure before I continued to dig into this. Because I still don't know much about php I was worried it may be some very common function that wasn't worth mentioning much, lol.

Answer (score 3):

That is some custom function defined in some file that you have.

It is **not** defined anywhere in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 0):

no its not a predefined one.its a customized one.
a predefined one is there which name is starts with show name which shows the source of the current file

```
 <?php
/* some code here */

show_source(__FILE__);    
?>
```